# Do grunt executions count as pilot executions for unlocks?

Tags: titanfall-2

When you stand behind an enemy pilot and hold the melee button, you perform an (interruptible) pilot execution. For multiplayer, there are multiple different animations and to unlock them you need to perform a certain amount of pilot executions.

I realized that you can also perform executions on NPC grunts. Do those also count as pilot executions for those unlocks?

Comment: In Titanfall 1 it was always explicit.  If it didn't say anything, could be Pilot/Grunt/Spectre, but if it did say Pilot, Grunts would not work.

Comment: I do not know for certain, but as @mmatthews said, if it states "Pilot" or "Pilot Executions" in the task/challenge description - I would say No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the "Inner Pieces" unlock which requires 50 pilot executions, performing an execution on a grunt does **not** count towards the 50 count.

I wish it did while I was working on the 50, it took some doing. The best way I found to get them was to use the map hack boost along with a stim pack. That way you can see where they are, and get there quickly :)

Comment: or map hack and cloak as it also works for Now you see me

Comment: Cloak works okayish, you can still see through cloak though if you have a keen eye. Another issue is that you still move slowly and it doesn't last that long. At first, I did try cloak, but found that it was hard to keep up with the target. I found it much easier to gain a positional advantage on an unaware target and then capitalize on the timing by using a stim pack.

Comment: yeah, I can see through it too, but it's either that or Phase Shift or MAYBE Holo Pilot